# Ansible pass multiple lines in input variable file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running ansible playbook via taking variables from a file outside

```
ansible-playbook -v /path/export.yml  --extra-vars '@input.json'
```

Now the file has only one line like below

```
{ out_file: exp_app_12.xml, control_file: export_control.xml}
```

Now I want to push multiple lines in the input.json file like below

```
{ out_file: exp_app_12.xml, control_file: export_control1.xml}
{ out_file: exp_app_13.xml, control_file: export_control2.xml}
{ out_file: exp_app_14.xml, control_file: export_control3.xml}
```

But it's not working , how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the JSON file in proper format like this;

```
ansible-playbook arcade.yml --extra-vars '{"pacman":"mrs","ghosts":["inky","pinky","clyde","sue"]}'
```

I think your JSON file is not in correct format, it must be like this;

```
[
{"out_file": "exp_app_12.xml","control_file": "export_control1.xml"},
{"out_file": "exp_app_12.xml","control_file": "export_control1.xml"},
{"out_file": "exp_app_12.xml","control_file": "export_control1.xml"}
]
```

Furthermore see the [ansible docs here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) for more understanding.

Comment: Thanks however it throws below error -"ERROR! Invalid extra vars data supplied. '@input.json' could not be made into a dictionary" - Is that the right way of passing variables in loop. I checked the documentation but it didnt show a use case for this type of scenario

Comment: Check this out, it might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558628/ansible-supply-extra-vars-as-nested-json

Comment: Thanks for your input , i am not looking for nested json. I want to implement the loop feature via reading from outside file

Comment: Then you cannot use the `--extra-vars '@input.json'` option.  You can only use that option with a properly formatted JSON file.